# Spring security 3.2 : How to bypass all the ajax requests in CSRFFilter

Tags: java, spring, security, csrf

Given that in spring security 3.2, to prevent CSRF attack we have to include CSRF tokens. It is applicable for ajax requests also. For ajax, we have to include the header token. But this seems a lot of rework. Overriding CSRFFilter is a way. Is there any better way by which I can bypass the token check for ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you achieve that and as you have not pasted your configuration, it's hard to help.

```
 http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new RequestMatcher() {
        private Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");
        private RegexRequestMatcher apiMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("/v[0-9]*/.*", null);

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            // No CSRF due to allowedMethod
            if(allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches())
                return false;

            // No CSRF due to api call
            if(apiMatcher.matches(request))
                return false;

            // CSRF for everything else that is not an API call or an allowedMethod
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.